# How to find users hidden in ssh connections

Tags: linux, authentication, ssh

I know I can print users using commands like `w`, `who`, `users` or `last`.

Unfortunately I can't print users with those commands if they logged using ldap with commands like:

- `ssh username@server.com bash --noprofile --norc`
- `ssh username@server.com /bin/bash/`

I also can't find them in `/var/run/utmp` and in `/var/log/wtmp`.

Is there any solution for that situation?

Comment: Better asked on Server Fault instead of Stack Overflow. In any case, look for children of the `sshd` process, for example using `ps u --ppid $(pgrep sshd)`.

Comment: Some more possibilities are listed here: https://www.baeldung.com/linux/list-connected-ssh-sessions